# Should i use REST as a 'communication medium' between modules of a larger system?

Tags: api, rest, communication

What i mean by the title is: we have a system with different submodules, each with their own (MVC web) application. I thought about creating a REST service that accesses the database and gives data to the applications so no application themselves can access a database directly. The API calls on all the methods that access the database and an application chooses, which to use etc. Basically the web application's models aren't themselves mapped to any database entities which is commonly done in MVC applications (like in ASP.net with entityframework).

Why i thought about this idea in the first place is because i couldn't figure out how to map models to database tables without having to map to all of the tables and their attributes (switching some off for some applications, we're using Phalcon) and have hundreds of unused models in each application. How bad of an idea is creating a REST API for this?

Answer (score 1):

If each application will access the same database you will have to maintain a lot of boilerplate model code (sql/orm). In case of some changes in database you'll have to propagate changes to every application.

In terms of maintenance it is better to expose business operations through web service which will be the only point of contact with database.

---

[image]

In case of web service changes inside database are not visible in applications

[image]

On the other hand without web service in front each change to database requires change in each application.